# struct as parameter to function: more efficient to copy or dereference?

Tags: c++, performance, function, parameters, struct

I am currently developing a simple clone detector for C, written in C++ and am asking myself endless questions about efficiency and how to optimise C++ code.

One question I have is regarding how to efficiently pass structs. If given a struct similar to something below:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int a;
    void *b;
} my_struct;
```

and a function which performs numerous operations (not assignments) on its my_struct parameter. This function is called for each node in an AST traversal (so quite a lot...) and, based on some preliminary reading, what I understand is that passing an instance of a struct (non-pointer) causes a copy of it to be made for the called function.

Therefore, is it more efficient to pass the struct as a pointer and then dereference?

```
void foo(my_struct *s) {
    // then dereference s->a...
```

Basically: **speed of copy vs. speed of dereference** is my question.

I assume, due to memory consumption, it would be smarter to pass the struct as a pointer but I have no idea of any side-effects regarding speed.

Comment: There's a lot of factors involved. These kind of things are almost impossible to guesstimate without actually benchmarking...

Comment: pointer any day. thats the power of C/C++. In the above case other than int, you have a pointer in your struct instance so, its just the matter of copying int to the caller stack which is negligible.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

In your case, your struct isn't much bigger than a pointer; it's likely that passing the entire struct as a function argument won't be much slower than passing a pointer.

Inside your function, accessing members of the struct via a pointer *might* be slower than accessing members of a local struct object. If so, then passing the struct directly might give you faster code overall if you're doing a lot inside the function. But that depends on the capabilities of the CPU and the generated code; it may be that member access has the same speed whether it's through a pointer or not.

The only way to answer the question is to measure the performance of your own code. Any answers you get will apply only to your own current situation, and could change on other targets systems or with a different version of the compiler.

Be sure you're telling your compiler to optimize your code. If you don't do that, there's not much point in measuring performance.

Comment: Hi, Keith. Thanks for your clarification. I'll be sure to set the optimisation flag and run some experiments to find the most efficient (in terms of time) version.

Answer (score 0):

Reading off the stack (copy) will be more reliably fast since the stack is less likly to be paged out of cache, however you also incure the cost of doing the copy, and potentially fill up the stack more.

My rule of thumb is to pass "simple" data by value and "complex" data by refrence. generally if my data is more than 8-16 bytes I start considering if it is worth passing a refrence.

The other thing to consider here is if it is even worth optimizing. I try to avoid doing things in unexpected ways (different from the rest of the code) unless I can prove that there is or will be a problem, as breaking a pattern will make the code harder to support.